# pycairo "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found." even after DLLs installed

Tags: python, windows-7, igraph, pycairo

I'm following the pycairo installation instructions here : 
http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/home/tamas/development/igraph/tutorial/install.html
to install pycairo for use with igraph.

However, even after running the installer and unzipping/copying all DLL's into the site-packages cairo directory according to the instructions, I still get the following error:

```
>>> import cairo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\cairo__init__.py", line 1, in 
    from _cairo import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>>
```

I am running python 2.6.6 under Windows 7.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Open _cairo.pyd in [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and figure out what it's missing.

Comment: Awesome! Turned out it needed a dll for freetype, which wasn't in the instructions.

Comment: @cip: I'm the guy who should be blamed for those instructions; can you please tell me the name of the missing DLL and where did you get it from? I'm flying blind here as I don't have a Windows machine.

Comment: @Tamas: Your tutorial has actually been extraordinarily helpful. I got the dll from the ftp site you link to - http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/dependencies/ the missing dll is freetype6.dll, found in freetype_2.4.4-1_win32.zip

Answer (score 0):

I kinda solved the problem installing the [Gtk-Bundle for Windows](http://www.gtk.org/download-windows.html), wich had the third party dll dependencies.

(I did a dirty solution by pasting the dlls directly into c:/Python27/lib/dist-packages/cairo, because I am not used to Windows anymore and don't know for sure what is the expected place for the dlls to go.)

But my scripts started to work at last.

Comment: I don't see a directory called c:\Python27\lib.  I see Lib and I see libs.  Under Lib there is no "dist-packages\cairo" there is a site-packages but no cairo.  There is a curl. Where is cairo supposed to come from?  I placed freetype6.dll on my path and I placed it in Lib\site-packages\curl.  I still get the error reported above.  I'm now searching the entire C drive for something called cairo.