# Trouble installing pycairo. Any suggestions on what to try next?

Tags: python, pip, pycairo

I have been trying to install pycairo for three days and I was wondering whether anyone could reproduce the error or if I am slowly starting to turn mad.

What I have tried:

I looked at the answers from [Installation of PyCairo on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48131876/installation-of-pycairo-on-windows) and [How do you install PyCairo (Cairo for Python) on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704407/how-do-you-install-pycairo-cairo-for-python-on-windows).

I tried installing pycairo using a file downloaded from [Python Extension Packages for Windows](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pycairo) but it says
`ERROR: pycairo-1.19.1-cp38-cp38-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`
I used the following command `pip install "C:\Users\...\Downloads\pycairo-1.19.1-cp38-cp38-win32.whl"`

I tried installing pycairo via pip `pip install pycairo` which gives me a really long error message:

```
Collecting pycairo
  Using cached pycairo-1.19.1.tar.gz (205 kB)
Installing collected packages: pycairo
    Running setup.py install for pycairo ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\caspa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\caspa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tjiuwot4\\pycairo\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\caspa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tjiuwot4\\pycairo\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\caspa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-pbvjvlu1\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\caspa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Include\pycairo'
         cwd: C:\Users\caspa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tjiuwot4\pycairo\
    Complete output (18 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cairo
    copying cairo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cairo
    copying cairo\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cairo
    copying cairo\py.typed -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cairo
    running build_ext
    building 'cairo._cairo' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\cairo
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=19 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=1 -Ic:\users\caspa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\caspa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.7.2\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tccairo/device.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\cairo/device.obj
    device.c
    C:\Users\caspa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tjiuwot4\pycairo\cairo\pycairo.h(37): fatal error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht ge”ffnet werden: "cairo.h": No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\caspa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\caspa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tjiuwot4\\pycairo\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\caspa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tjiuwot4\\pycairo\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\caspa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-pbvjvlu1\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\caspa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Include\pycairo' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I get the same error message when trying to install [PyGoject](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which contains pycairo, via pip.

I found something that should be supposed to fix the error, but unfortunately the link in the [forum](http://digitalpbk.blogspot.com/2012/03/installing-pygtk-pypango-and-pycairo-on.html) is dead. I went to the official download page (I believe) [cairographics.org](https://www.cairographics.org/download/) and its a dead link as well.

Another thing I tried: I went to [the Cairo Docs on getting started](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html), but it's unfortunately only for Ubuntu/Linux/IOS.

Comment: When you try to install using pip do you run cmd as administrator?

Comment: "*pycairo-1.19.1-cp38-cp38-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform*" The wheel is for 32-bit Python 3.8. Either your Python is not 3.8 or it's not 32-bit. If you gonna use Python 3.8 64-bit download a wheel for 64-bit Python 3.8.

Comment: I'm using python 3.7.4 32 Bit, I did try running it as an administrator, same error unfortunatly. But thanks for your comments.

Comment: Then download and install from `pycairo-1.19.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl`?

Answer (score 9):

I've ran into a similar error to this as well, so here's what worked for me. Go to https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html for more info. You'll have to run one of these five commands to set up pkg-config on your computer prior to running the install command.

- Ubuntu/Debian: `sudo apt install libcairo2-dev pkg-config python3-dev`
- macOS/Homebrew: `brew install cairo pkg-config`
- Arch Linux: `sudo pacman -S cairo pkgconf`
- Fedora: `sudo dnf install cairo-devel pkg-config python3-devel`
- penSUSE: `sudo zypper install cairo-devel pkg-config python3-devel`

Then run:
`import cairo`

Hope that works!

Answer (score 0):

I'm new with Python, so I'm not really sure what's going on, but this works for me.

Simply change the "**pip**" to "**pip3**" and it'll magically work.
As of this writing, I'm using Python 3.8 64-bit so my command is this:

```
pip3 install pycairo-1.19.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

From what I understand, this seems to be an incompatibility since Python 2 life has ended and lost support just early this year. So pretty much all the tutorial is outdated and didn't work.