# When installing ipykernel to work with pypy and VS Code, I encountered an error: "Building wheel for pyzmq (PEP 517) ... error"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, pypy

[Error displayed in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWF1G.png)

How can this error be corrected? Thank you in advance for answer.

Comment: Please post code as text, not images, so they are easier to read. What commands cause the error?

Answer (score 0):

As the warning says, you need to update the pip.
Using the following code to update pip and setuptools:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

You can reinstall after the update is complete.

Comment: Made an update with these commands. Then I reinstalled ipikernel. As a result, this is the error: "note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyzmq
Failed to build pyzmq
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyzmq, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects"

Comment: @Togner https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70508775/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-pycairo-which-is-required-to-install-pyprojec Can this issue solve your problem?