# Error "Invalid version: '0.23ubuntu1' (package: distro-info)"

Tags: python

Originally, my app crashed with error ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycairo (in the picture)

[Failed to build pycairo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXawG.jpg)

I tried to fix it by running several commands

- sudo apt install libcairo2-dev
- sudo apt install cloud-init

Gave the same error. No fix.

then I tried uninstalling the requirements.txt and reinstalled

- pip uninstall -r requirements.txt
- pip install -r requirements.txt

Did not solve the issue.

then I tried the below command, but I still got the same error "Failed building wheel for pycairo":

- pip3 install --upgrade pip (from this thread: [ERROR: Could not build wheels for scipy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61365790/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-scipy-which-use-pep-517-and-cannot-be-installe)

then I tried this command:

- pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

and I got this error in the picture: "Invalid version: '0.23ubuntu1'"

[Invalid version: '0.23ubuntu1'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVUeC.jpg)

I tried to also delete this package but it's showing that package not found:

command I used: sudo apt-get remove distro-info

Error:

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

Package 'distro-info' is not installed, so not removed

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 283 not upgraded.

I searched for solutions but did not find any regarding the error "Invalid version: '0.23ubuntu1'". Now, when I run "flask run", I get error: -bash: /home/ktai/.local/bin/flask: No such file or directory

Would appreciate any help!

I tried several command lines but nothing worked

Comment: Many problems can be solved by searching for the error message. In this case, a search for "Could not build wheels for pycairo" turns up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70508775/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-pycairo-which-is-required-to-install-pyprojec , which appears to address your problem.

Answer (score 13):

I learned from this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1407138) that there is a "bug" with versions of setuptools causing this specific `Invalid version: '0.23ubuntu1'` error.

Despite seeing errors with all sorts of pip commands including `pip install`, I was surprised to see that this downgrade command (from the answer linked) appears to resolve the issue:

```
pip install --upgrade --user setuptools==58.3.0
```

Comment: Do not do this. Instead upgrade to newest version of `setuptools >= 67.6.0` where issue is now fixed.

Comment: By the way it makes no sense to give both `--upgrade` and a fixed version.

Comment: pip Installing `setuptools` 68 does not correct error messages on Linux Mint 22.04

Comment: @Teque5 Still seeing this with setuptools 68.1.2

Answer (score 5):

This error arises from PEP 440 (Python Enhancement Proposal #440), which enforces conventions for naming of Python packages, and this error seems to really only happen on Debian-based distros like Ubuntu. For example, I have been trying to install a package via `pip` and get an error:

`pkg_resources.extern.packaging.version.InvalidVersion: Invalid version: '1.1build1' (package: distro-info)`

So it's telling us that `1.1build1` is an invalid version name per PEP 440, and it's probably getting the `distro-info` package from, in my case, Ubuntu (came preinstalled).

I can get around this by using a Python virtual environment and not allowing it to use `system-site-packages`, sometimes called "global packages".

**The solution is to remove the offending package and reinstall a version of it that meets PEP 440 requirements (e.g. following the "0.0.0" convention. "1.2.0" for example is fine, "1.2build3" is not).**

```
pip uninstall -y distro-info
pip install distro-info==1.0
```

Additionally, within PyCharm, I can navigate to the Python Interpreter settings, choose the interpreter I am using from the Python Interpreter dropdown, and confirm that the version of `distro-info` it's trying to use is `1.1build1`. To "upgrade" this to `1.0`, I can double-click on the "1.0" under the "Latest Version" column and select "Install Package" from the modal that pops up.

If this or the above command to remove `distro-info` isn't working, you can use this same window to remove `distro-info` and then simply run `pip install distro-info==1.0`.

[image: PyCharm's "Python Interpreter" settings]

Comment: Coming here from the [basic Docker-Python tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/language/python/build-images/). In typical Python fashion, the `docker build` was failing when `distro-info` in the `requirement.txt` violated this compliance rule, unjustifiably preventing installation. Changing the txt entry to `distro-info==1.0` allowed the `docker build` to go a bit forward (it still continued to fail due to other messy errors). The joys of working with Python.

Comment: This worked for me.  Thanks.  But no need to unintsall.  I simply did `python3 -m pip install --upgrade distro-info`

Answer (score 4):

For me the issue was being caused by the `distro-info` Python package having been installed via APT rather than by pip. Even after manually upgrading `distro-info` and playing around with the different versions of `setuptools` in other answers it kept reoccuring.

This solved my problem (on Ubuntu 20.04):

```bash
sudo apt remove python3-distro-info
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you using ubuntu 20.04 by chance?
I had a similar issue but it had to do nothing with pycairo so the situation might be different for you.
The existence of `distro-info` (with a version not compliant to PEP-440) among my Python packages was leading to the error message from your post's title whenever i tried to install another package.

For me, this one helped: (so you were close with the apt-get remove...)

```
python3 -m pip uninstall -y distro-info
```

In my case, it seems like it didnt break anything important so i will keep it like this.
But there is no guarantee the same works for you as well. Also, you might get it back the next time you install packages from your requirements.txt file.

If I understood [this thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/distro-info/+bug/2003583) correctly, there might be updates with a compliant version of this package depending on which Ubuntu version you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for all the answers. To answer my own question, I was finally able to fix the issue by updating all the required packages.

Now there are no updates needed, and the app works again.

```
0 updates can be applied immediately.

The list of available updates is more than a week old.
To check for new updates run: sudo apt update
```

Answer (score 2):

For me doing what sean said broke my pip install, but upgrading setuptools to the current version (which is `setuptools-67.6.0`, as of answering) fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading this using Ubuntu 22.04, and based on answers by @Teque5 above, the correct solution is to upgrade the offending packages.

In my case, the errors were:

```
DEPRECATION: devscripts 2.22.1ubuntu1 has a non-standard version number. pip 23.3 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to upgrade to a newer version of devscripts or contact the author to suggest that they release a version with a conforming version number. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12063
DEPRECATION: reportbug 11.4.1ubuntu1 has a non-standard version number. pip 23.3 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to upgrade to a newer version of reportbug or contact the author to suggest that they release a version with a conforming version number. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12063
```

And the solution:

```
pip install --upgrade --user devscripts setuptools reportbug
```