# Manim not installing on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, manim

I did `pip install manim` and got an error:

```
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

Then I tried `!pip install manimce` and got an exception:

```
Exception: You have installed Manim from `manimce` PyPI package which is deprecated and no longer updated. Please uninstall `manimce` and install Manim from `manim` PyPI package.
```

Plz help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip install manimce` is definitely wrong and refers to an outdated version of Manim.

Regarding your error during `pip install manim` it should tell you where the problem lies, i.e. which Python package could not be installed.

I have no experience with Colab, but other users on the ManimCE Discord server do... [Where can I find more resources for learning Manim?](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/faq/general.html?highlight=discord#where-can-i-find-more-resources-for-learning-manim)

**Ok to give the definitive answer here:** it is in the ManimCE online [documentation](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/installation/jupyter.html#google-colaboratory), in order to get a full install including LaTeX you need to run the following commands:

```
!sudo apt update
!sudo apt install libcairo2-dev ffmpeg \
    texlive texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-extra \
    texlive-latex-recommended texlive-science \
    tipa libpango1.0-dev
!pip install manim
!pip install IPython --upgrade
```

Comment: I ran your code without the first and last lines and it still worked.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

This may be happening because you didn't install the requirements to run manim.

**Edit: My bad for the previous answer. Try this instead:**

### Correct Solution

```
!sudo apt update
!sudo apt install libcairo2-dev ffmpeg texlive texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-extra texlive-latex-recommended texlive-science tipa libpango1.0-dev
!pip install manim
!pip install IPython --upgrade
```

After finishing this, a prompt for restarting runtime will appear below the cell.

Restart the runtime, skip the cell above, and start using `manim` by executing `from manim import *`

[Source](https://financial-engineering.medium.com/i-found-a-way-to-run-mamin-on-google-colab-ef37d164c960)

---

### Old Answer

**Ignore and do not follow.**
This [answer of a similar past question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70883557/13919908) might help.

Solution described (and modified according to Google Colab's format):

```
!apt-get install sox ffmpeg libcairo2 libcairo2-dev
!apt-get install texlive-full
!pip install manim
```

Comment: Still getting the same error :[