# ERROR: Could not build wheels for pomegranate, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda, pomegranate

I was trying to install `pomegranate 0.6.0` on my macbook and I met an error:

```bash
Building wheels for collected packages: pomegranate
  Building wheel for pomegranate (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [204 lines of output]
      In file included from pomegranate/base.c:256:
      In file included from /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:5:
      In file included from /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12:
      In file included from /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1940:
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with "          "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
      #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
       ^
      pomegranate/base.c:4072:134: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          __pyx_t_3 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_1, __pyx_t_2); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_3); __pyx_t_2++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 330; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                           ^~~~~~~
      pomegranate/base.c:5083:142: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
                __pyx_t_4 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_5, __pyx_t_10); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_4); __pyx_t_10++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 395; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                                   ^~~~~~~
      pomegranate/base.c:5075:141: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
                __pyx_t_4 = PyList_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_5, __pyx_t_10); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_4); __pyx_t_10++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 395; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                                  ^~~~~~~
      pomegranate/base.c:4991:138: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              __pyx_t_4 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_1, __pyx_t_2); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_4); __pyx_t_2++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 394; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                               ^~~~~~~
      pomegranate/base.c:4983:137: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              __pyx_t_4 = PyList_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_1, __pyx_t_2); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_4); __pyx_t_2++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 394; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                              ^~~~~~~
      pomegranate/base.c:8574:134: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          __pyx_t_3 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_1, __pyx_t_2); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_3); __pyx_t_2++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[2]; __pyx_lineno = 794; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                           ^~~~~~~
      pomegranate/base.c:10266:40: error: no member named 'tp_print' in 'struct _typeobject'
        __pyx_type_11pomegranate_4base_Model.tp_print = 0;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
      pomegranate/base.c:10274:45: error: no member named 'tp_print' in 'struct _typeobject'
        __pyx_type_11pomegranate_4base_GraphModel.tp_print = 0;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
      pomegranate/base.c:10299:40: error: no member named 'tp_print' in 'struct _typeobject'
        __pyx_type_11pomegranate_4base_State.tp_print = 0;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
      pomegranate/base.c:10819:22: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                          (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                           ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:261:7: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
            PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) :                    \
            ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
      #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                        ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
      ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      pomegranate/base.c:10819:22: warning: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                          (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                           ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:262:14: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
            ((void)PyUnicode_AsUnicode(_PyObject_CAST(op)),\
                   ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:1: note: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
      ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      pomegranate/base.c:10819:22: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                          (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                           ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:264:8: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
             PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op)))
             ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
      #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                        ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
      ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      pomegranate/base.c:10819:52: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                          (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                                         ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:261:7: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
            PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) :                    \
            ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
      #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                        ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
      ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      pomegranate/base.c:10819:52: warning: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                          (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                                         ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:262:14: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
            ((void)PyUnicode_AsUnicode(_PyObject_CAST(op)),\
                   ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:1: note: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
      ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      pomegranate/base.c:10819:52: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                          (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                                         ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:264:8: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
             PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op)))
             ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
      #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                        ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
      ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      pomegranate/base.c:10835:26: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                              (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                               ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:261:7: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
            PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) :                    \
            ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
      #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                        ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
      ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      pomegranate/base.c:10835:26: warning: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                              (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                               ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:262:14: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
            ((void)PyUnicode_AsUnicode(_PyObject_CAST(op)),\
                   ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:1: note: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
      ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      pomegranate/base.c:10835:26: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                              (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                               ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:264:8: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
             PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op)))
             ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
      #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                        ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
      ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      pomegranate/base.c:10835:59: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                              (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                                                ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:261:7: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
            PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) :                    \
            ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
      #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                        ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
      ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      pomegranate/base.c:10835:59: warning: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                              (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                                                ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:262:14: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
            ((void)PyUnicode_AsUnicode(_PyObject_CAST(op)),\
                   ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:1: note: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
      ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      pomegranate/base.c:10835:59: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                              (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                                                ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:264:8: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
             PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op)))
             ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
      #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                        ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
      ^
      /Users/zhengrongyan/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      19 warnings and 3 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pomegranate
  Running setup.py clean for pomegranate
Failed to build pomegranate
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pomegranate, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

In short, I think the main problem is demonstrated at the bottom of the error message.

```bash
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pomegranate, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I also tried the method to install some package using `brew`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76298959/21151679

But it didn't work.

btw, I am using anaconda python 3.9.

Update(26/09/2023): installed `pomegranate 0.14.9` successfully with `python 3.8.18` or later versions in anaconda/local machine but it doesn't work for `pomegranate 0.14.8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is: "no member named 'tp_print' in 'struct _typeobject'". The `tp_print` method was removed from the API in Python 3.8. The error means the code is intended for Python <= 3.8. Downgrade to Python 3.8 or try more recent version of `pomegranate`. The current latest version is [1.0.3](https://pypi.org/project/pomegranate/1.0.3/); version [0.6.0](https://pypi.org/project/pomegranate/0.6.0/) was released in 2016; it seems it's simply too old for the newer Pythons.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I created a new anaconda environment with python 3.7 on my windows laptop and it works. It seems that `pomegranate 0.6.0` still too old for `python 3.8.18` but this is the oldest version that I can install in anaconda.

Comment: With Python 3.8 I got a different error: "has no member named 'exc_traceback'". The error seems to be from [outdated Cython-compiled files](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%22has+no+member+named+exc_traceback%22). I ran `pip install Cython` before `pip install pomegranate==0.6.0` but got SyntaxError in Cython. Seems like a very buggy version.

Comment: I looked at the GitHub page and it only has two version: `1.0.0` and `0.14.8`. I think `0.14.8` is the one we want instead of `0.6.0` (I cannot find any information about `0.6.0` btw). I tried `pip install pomegranate==0.14.8` and it works. (Here is the link about repository https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate/tree/master)

Comment: I see a lot of releases at PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/pomegranate/1.0.3/#history It seems the author(s) don't create tags for releases. `pip install --upgrade pomegranate` should install the latest, as well as `pip install pomegranate==1.0.3`

Comment: I see. I think in the end they only keep two versions: the latest one and `0.14.8` since the latest one is a ground-up rewrite and the API is significantly different. I think it's better to follow the instructions on GitHub.