# pyFLTK (python v2.7, pyFLTK 1.3): ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, fltk

I just used the pyFLTK installer ([http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyfltk/](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyfltk/).)). That gave me the DLL load error.

I read that you have to install FLTK as well. Where exactly do I install this?

As well, after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731786/pycairo-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found), I found out that _fltk.pyd was apparently missing LIBGCC_S_DW2-1.DLL, LIBSTDC++-6.DLL, MSVCR71.DLL, GPSVC.DLL. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the alternative installer at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyfltk.