# Import Error when run django with wsgi (apache)

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I found the problem when I run django from apache.
When I run my program in debug mode ( manage.py runserver in cmd ) , everything is work.
But when I run with apache, It show error:

```
ImportError at /systeminformation/ DLL load failed:
The specified module could not be found.
```

The error is occur when I import `win32file`. I use django 1.5.2 with apache 2.2 and run with `mod_wsgi`.

Anyone can solve this problem?

thank you very much

Comment: couple of document recommande to use linux for apache instead of windows. the thing you can do is to reuse the windows installation CD if you can find the DLL and copy it to the windows install folder.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are probably missing some DLL. Run win32file through [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), and see what's missing. Kudos to [Ignacio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731786/pycairo-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found) for this app link.