# Error importing scipy.linalg on windows (python 3.3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I am using python 3.3 on Windows. I downloaded **scipy-0.13.2.win32-py3.3.exe** from [scipy-lib](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy) and installed it. However, when I tried to load scipy.linalg, interpreter displayed the following errors:

```
>>> import scipy.linalg
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
  import scipy.linalg
 File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py", line 157, in <module>
  from .misc import *
 File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 5, in <module>
  from . import blas
 File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 131, in <module>
  from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

How can I resolve this issue? Between, I checked installed library modules on my PC with the github modules at [linealg-scipy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/master/scipy/linalg) and they are latest, so no issue there, I guess.

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/INSTALL.txt and ensured all the dependencies (e.g. NumPy) are met?

Comment: Yes, I installed NumPy before installing SciPy. NumPy works perfect, but I am unable to find any other dependency which I haven't met for importing SciPy.

Comment: Check out answer to: ["ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4731796/2419207)

Comment: I am getting following logs:
Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.
From http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/interpreting_errors.htm, missing a forward or implicit dependency is an error. But, where can I find that missing dependency in logs?

Comment: I found following dlls missing:
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL ;
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL ;
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL ;
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL ;
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL ;
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-1.DLL ;
DCOMP.DLL ;
IESHIMS.DLL ;
LIBIOMP5MD.DLL

Comment: But then, I checked the same with linalg library in NumPy. However, it is loading well and good in python interpreter, the dependency walker shows the same above dll's missing for lapack_lite.pyd in numpy.linalg directory.

Comment: Problem solved:Installed **Scipy-stack-13.10.11.win32-py3.3.exe** from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy-stack . From now on, I would recommend scipy-stack instead of installing packages separately, otherwise one may waste his/her day searching for dlls!!

Comment: @ologn13 Add your last comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue in both Python 2.7/3, you can install scipy from [here](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/download.html)

It will work better than the version from [this deposit](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs).