# 'No-name-in-module' import error

Tags: python, pydev, python-import

I'm getting a 'No-name-in-module' import error whenever I try to import `linalg` from `scipy`
I have no trouble importing scipy or anything else from scipy. For some reason it doesn't like linalg. Oddly, eclipse includes linalg under auto-completion.

I have tried:

- Removing the interpreter and then adding it again
- Adding site-tools, the scipy directory, and even the scipy/linalg directory to libraries under the python interpreter preferences.
- Deleting all class files
- Importing linalg as a different name
- Reinstalling eclipse
- freaking out

I'm running anaconda on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350153/error-importing-scipy-linalg-on-windows-python-3-3

Comment: I'm running anaconda so the whole stack should be installed. I updated everything via anaconda and am still having the same issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem seems to be coming from pylint. Error disappears if I add: `# pylint: disable-msg=E0611` to the line

Comment: I switched to using pyflakes and/or flake8 instead of pylint because of this false positive.